# Npm install failed on semantic-ui due to gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

I'm trying to install the dependencies for this react app. I have the packages in my package.json and am running `npm install`. The output is:

```
> semantic-ui@2.3.3 install /srv/org/reactsgo/app/front_end/node_modules/semantic-ui
> gulp install

gulp[10488]: ../src/node_contextify.cc:637:static void node::contextify::ContextifyScript::New(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&): Assertion `args[1]->IsString()' failed.
 1: 0x8b8210 node::Abort() [gulp]
 2: 0x8b82e5  [gulp]
 3: 0x8eb237 node::contextify::ContextifyScript::New(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [gulp]
 4: 0xb4daa8  [gulp]
 5: 0xb4fa12 v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [gulp]
 6: 0x1a851fd841bd
Aborted
```

I've tried to clean my cache with `npm clean cache --force`. I've built and rebuilt. I always get the same problem when I do the semantic-ui install even when I simply try to `npm install semantic-ui` on its own.

Am I hitting a versioning issue? My node is v10.8.0 and my npm is 6.2.0.

Anyone have a similar issue and a fix?

EDIT: On Debian 8 jessie

Comment: Are you on windows?

Comment: debian 8 jessie

Comment: Try deleting the node_modules, `npm clean cache --force`, `npm install gulp-header --save-dev`, and `npm install`

Comment: hit the same error after doing all of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed running `npm install natives` then rerunning `npm install`

Comment: would you please explain more? what is natives package?